# Binary content cache system between servers via NGINX

Tags: caching, architecture, nginx

We have a data storage, there are a lot of binary content, let's call it A-server. Also i have a C-server which uses it content and a have a very little cache(L1). And also we have a B-server where will be cache with big amount of space(which will be proxy requests to A-server if there isn't needed content. There will be L2 cache. So the question is how it should be designed? Now we mount data storage to A-server via nfs. But this solution is bad for us. Also the channel between B-C is very very unstable. We think about nginx proxy system. But first question is how to add middleware
between nginx and FS on B-server so it can be used as our cache system. And do we need to write our own cache system(on B-server)? Or use some ready? If use - which?

Simple scheme as i see it.

C-server -> B-server -> NGINX -> cache middleware -> FS or -> C-server -> NGINX -> FS

PS. If you think that theme is incorrect feel free to correct it. And sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nginx native caching proxy.